# Player won't move correctly due to gravity force pushing him into the ground

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I am making a tilemap platformer with pygame ad I defined the X and Y movement for the player and also a Y force that represents the gravity force to make it jump correctly. However, when my player falls off to the ground and the game begins, it doesn't move correctly neither to the right nor to the left direction due to the gravity force that **keeps pushing him to the down**. In addition to that, when the player jumps and i move it to the right, it's like it doesn't recognize the collision with the bottom rect of the wall (*see gif below for a visual explanation of that*).

I tried disabling that gravity force when the player hits the ground and enable it when the player jumps but it didn't work as expected and I've got problems managing collisions (*also, it doesn't make sense to disable gravity, right?*)

[image: Here's a gif of the issue i'm facing with]

Here's my Player class:

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

        self.game = game

        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.move_left = self.move_right = False

        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(x, y)
        self.acc = pg.math.Vector2(0, GRAVITY)
        self.vel = pg.math.Vector2(0, 0)

    def jump(self):
        self.vel.y -= 3

    def update(self):
        self.vel.x = 0

        if self.move_left:
            self.vel.x = -PLAYER_SPEED
        if self.move_right:
            self.vel.x = PLAYER_SPEED

        self.vel += self.acc

        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.x = self.pos.x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = self.pos.y * TILESIZE

        if self.vel.y > 0.5:
            self.vel.y = 0.5

        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
        if hits:
            if self.vel.x > 0:
                self.pos -= self.vel
                self.rect.right = hits[0].rect.left
                self.vel.x = 0
            if self.vel.x < 0:
                self.pos -= self.vel
                self.rect.left = hits[0].rect.right
                self.vel.x = 0

        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
        if hits:
            if self.vel.y > 0:
                self.pos -= self.vel
                self.rect.bottom = hits[0].rect.top
                self.vel.y = 0
            if self.vel.y < 0:
                self.pos -= self.vel
                self.rect.top = hits[0].rect.bottom
                self.vel.y = 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have different types of collisions, on a roof, on a wall (, on the ground)?

Comment: Should I?
Actually I'm following some tutorial series on YT and seems like they all used groups in order to detect collisions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is calling `spritecollide` twice, combined with updating the position:

```py
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
        if hits:
            # If one of these conditions are true, the position will be updated,
            # continuing the previous velocity, i.e. going through the roof.
            if self.vel.x > 0:
                self.pos -= self.vel
                # [...]
            if self.vel.x < 0:
                self.pos -= self.vel
                # [...]

        # After you go through the roof, there's no more collision...
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
        if hits:
            if self.vel.y > 0:
                self.pos -= self.vel
                # [...]
                self.vel.y = 0
```

Two cases, with the current code:

- If you jump without x-speed, you do not update the position (aka go through the roof). So the second call of `spritecollide` does return a non empty `hits` and you will bounce on the roof.
- If the x-speed is non null, you update the position go through the roof, and the second `if hits:` is False.

Solution: Call `hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)` only once, and do not change the position before all the velocities are updated.

Comment: I changed my code as you can see [here](https://pastebin.com/rjNpS1fM) but now seems like it's not recognizing any collision.

The closet solution was by [not changing the position before all the velocities get updated](https://pastebin.com/ZE1Di44f) but now seems like it is not colliding with the "x" axis of my walls.